# Constructor function is getting called each time when clicking on element in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, css, angular

Here is the constructor of a class

```
constructor(public userData:userMetaData) {
    this.colors = this.userData.firstLetterColors;
    this.userData.currentPage = 'chats';
    this.math = Math;
}
```

In HTML I have the following code:

```
<mdl-list *ngFor="let item of notifications" (click)="seeNotification()" >
  <p class="firstLetter" [innerHTML]="item.title.slice(0,-(item.title.length-1))" [style.backgroundColor]="userData.firstLetterColors[math.floor(math.random()*9)+1]">F</p>
</mdl-list>
```

The first letter of the list should pick some random color from the  `this.colors` array. It is picking the color. But, whenever I click on it, the background color is also changing. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: You are binding to `style.backgroundColor` so it's normal that the background color changes! I don't understand what do you expect?

Comment: loop executes only once, at that time background-color(random color from given array) will set for all items. again when i click why background-color is changing onclick?

Comment: Okey! Try to move `(click)="seeNotification()"` to `p` tag !

Comment: tried that as well didn't help